# Sorting by a computed MySQL field in CakePHP 2.x pagination

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.x

I have the MySQL query for the result I need:

```
SELECT `delivery_date` FROM `order_grids` ORDER BY str_to_date(`delivery_date`, "%b %d, %Y") DESC
```

As we have custom ORDER BY so I am  facing issue to implement it in CakePHP 2.x.

Generally, in case of normal field sorting we do as below. I have a `VARCHAR` type field `delivery_date` which stores date in format `Jan 21, 2015` and need sorting on that column.

I already have the MySQL query as shown above:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('delivery_date','Delivery Date');
```

Please assist.

Comment: You can use a virtual field. However, storing dates in a VARCHAR is not a good idea.

Comment: @InigoFlores - actually  this is an ongoing project so we cannot change the  field type. Can you please explain how i can use my sql query so it works in cake php way.

Comment: I understand. See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by creating a virtual field.

> Since virtual fields behave much like regular fields when doing find’s, `Controller::paginate()` will be able to sort by virtual fields too.

Add the following to your `OrderGrid` model:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['delivery_date_proper'] = sprintf('STR_TO_DATE(%s.delivery_date, "%%b %%d, %%Y") ', $this->alias);
}
```

This will allow you to sort by `delivery_date_proper` when paginating.

See

- Cookbook 2.x: Virtual fields: [Pagination and virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#pagination-and-virtual-fields).